# AWS IoT rules SQL query Select not returning expected values from shadow

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I am trying to create a rule that publishes the selected data from the things shadow.

My SQL query is

```
SELECT state FROM '$aws/things/+/shadow/update/accepted'
```

I would expect this to return both the desired and reported but it only return one object and not nested.

```
{
  temp: 200,
  io: false
}
```

instead of

```
{
  desired: {
        temp: 200,
        io: true
    },
  reported: {
        temp: 200,
        io: false
    }
}
```

so then I tried doing

```
SELECT state.desired, state.reported FROM '$aws/things/+/shadow/update/accepted'
```

and I only recieve the the object, basically which ever I put at the end of the SELECT statement after the ,

Anyone have any idea? I am trying to strip out all the metadata and timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer for whoever comes across this in the future. In the rule creation above where you enter your SQL Query, you need to change the SQL version to beta.